# Flask Deployment with Gunicorn SyntaxError: multiple exception types must be parenthesized

Tags: python, flask, langchain

recently i ran into this error while updating my flask project with Gunicorn as WSGI Server, how can i fix this :(

```
gian-luca@MBPvonGianLuca backend % python3 -m gunicorn main:api
[2023-05-12 16:53:41 +0200] [66121] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 20.1.0
[2023-05-12 16:53:41 +0200] [66121] [INFO] Listening at: http://127.0.0.1:8000 (66121)
[2023-05-12 16:53:41 +0200] [66121] [INFO] Using worker: sync
[2023-05-12 16:53:41 +0200] [66122] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 66122
[2023-05-12 16:53:42 +0200] [66122] [ERROR] Exception in worker process
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.11/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 589, in spawn_worker
    worker.init_process()
  File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.11/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 134, in init_process
    self.load_wsgi()
  File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.11/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 146, in load_wsgi
    self.wsgi = self.app.wsgi()
                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.11/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 67, in wsgi
    self.callable = self.load()
                    ^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.11/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 58, in load
    return self.load_wsgiapp()
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.11/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 48, in load_wsgiapp
    return util.import_app(self.app_uri)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.11/site-packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 359, in import_app
    mod = importlib.import_module(module)
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/python@3.11/3.11.2_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1206, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1178, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1149, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 690, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 940, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 241, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/Users/gian-luca/Documents/luca/CareReact/backend/main.py", line 1, in <module>
    from langchain.llms import OpenAI
  File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.11/site-packages/langchain/__init__.py", line 6, in <module>
    from langchain.agents import MRKLChain, ReActChain, SelfAskWithSearchChain
  File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.11/site-packages/langchain/agents/__init__.py", line 2, in <module>
    from langchain.agents.agent import (
  File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.11/site-packages/langchain/agents/agent.py", line 15, in <module>
    from langchain.agents.tools import InvalidTool
  File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.11/site-packages/langchain/agents/tools.py", line 8, in <module>
    from langchain.tools.base import BaseTool, Tool, tool
  File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.11/site-packages/langchain/tools/__init__.py", line 13, in <module>
    from langchain.tools.gmail import (
  File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.11/site-packages/langchain/tools/gmail/__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    from langchain.tools.gmail.create_draft import GmailCreateDraft
  File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.11/site-packages/langchain/tools/gmail/create_draft.py", line 11, in <module>
    from langchain.tools.gmail.base import GmailBaseTool
  File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.11/site-packages/langchain/tools/gmail/base.py", line 17, in <module>
    from googleapiclient.discovery import Resource
  File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.11/site-packages/googleapiclient/discovery.py", line 57, in <module>
    from googleapiclient import _auth, mimeparse
  File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.11/site-packages/googleapiclient/_auth.py", line 34, in <module>
    import oauth2client.client
  File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.11/site-packages/oauth2client/client.py", line 45, in <module>
    from oauth2client import crypt
  File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.11/site-packages/oauth2client/crypt.py", line 55, in <module>
    from oauth2client import _pycrypto_crypt
  File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.11/site-packages/oauth2client/_pycrypto_crypt.py", line 17, in <module>
    from Crypto.PublicKey import RSA
  File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.11/site-packages/Crypto/PublicKey/RSA.py", line 585
    except ValueError, IndexError:
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
SyntaxError: multiple exception types must be parenthesized
[2023-05-12 16:53:42 +0200] [66122] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 66122)
[2023-05-12 16:53:42 +0200] [66121] [INFO] Shutting down: Master
[2023-05-12 16:53:42 +0200] [66121] [INFO] Reason: Worker failed to boot.
```

Here is my main.py Flask Server:

```
from langchain.llms import OpenAI
from langchain.chains import ConversationalRetrievalChain
from langchain.embeddings.openai import OpenAIEmbeddings
from langchain.text_splitter import CharacterTextSplitter
from langchain.vectorstores import Chroma
from langchain.document_loaders import PagedPDFSplitter
import json
import os
from flask import Flask, request, jsonify, send_file
from functools import wraps
import datetime
from firebase_admin import credentials, auth, initialize_app, firestore, storage
from flask_cors import CORS, cross_origin
from werkzeug.utils import secure_filename
import tempfile
import requests
import mimetypes

import logging
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)


OPEN_AI_API_KEY = os.environ.get('OPENAI_API_KEY')
embeddings = OpenAIEmbeddings(openai_api_key=OPEN_AI_API_KEY)

api = Flask(__name__)
cred = credentials.Certificate('fbAdminConfig.json')
firebase = initialize_app(
    cred, {'storageBucket': 'test.appspot.com'})
db = firestore.client()
CORS(api, resources={r"/*": {"origins": "*"}})
bucket = storage.bucket()

UPLOAD_FOLDER = 'uploads'
api.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'] = UPLOAD_FOLDER




def check_token(f):
    @wraps(f)
    def wrap(*args, **kwargs):
        if not request.headers.get('authorization'):
            return {'message': 'No token provided'}
        try:
            user = auth.verify_id_token(request.headers['authorization'])
            request.user = user
            api.logger.info('User ' + user['email'] + ' authenticated')
        except:
            return {'message': 'Invalid token provided.'}
        return f(*args, **kwargs)
    return wrap


def upload_blob(source_file_name, destination_blob_name):
    blob = bucket.blob(destination_blob_name)

    blob.upload_from_filename(source_file_name)

    return blob.public_url


def download_blob(blob_name, destination_file_name):
    blob = bucket.blob(blob_name)
    blob.download_to_filename(destination_file_name)


def check_file_owner(user_uid, file_id):
    file_ref = db.collection('uploaded_files').document(file_id)
    file_data = file_ref.get()

    if file_data.exists and file_data.to_dict()['user_uid'] == user_uid:
        return True
    return False



def EmbedPDF(doc, uid):
    loader = PagedPDFSplitter(doc)
    documents = loader.load()
    text_splitter = CharacterTextSplitter(
        separator=' ', chunk_size=1000, chunk_overlap=200)
    documents = text_splitter.split_documents(documents)
    vectorstore = Chroma.from_documents(
        documents=documents, embedding=embeddings, persist_directory=uid)
    print(f'Created Chroma with ChatId {uid}')
    return vectorstore


def save_chat_message(uid, message, response, source1, source2, source3, source4):
    chat_ref = db.collection('chats').document(uid).collection('messages')
    chat_data = {
        'message': message,
        'response': response,
        'source1': source1,
        'source2': source2,
        'source3': source3,
        'source4': source4,
        'timestamp': datetime.datetime.utcnow()
    }
    chat_ref.add(chat_data)


def get_chathistory(uid, limit=10):
    chat_ref = db.collection('chats').document(uid).collection('messages')
    chat_data = chat_ref.order_by(
        "timestamp", direction=firestore.Query.DESCENDING).limit(limit).stream()

    res = []
    for doc in chat_data:
        res.append(({doc.to_dict()['message']}, {doc.to_dict()['response']}))

    chat_history = [(list(query)[0], list(result)[0]) for query, result in res]

    return chat_history


@api.route('/upload', methods=['POST'])
@check_token
def upload_file():
    if 'file' not in request.files:
        return jsonify({'message': 'No file part'})

    file = request.files['file']
    if file.filename == '':
        return jsonify({'message': 'No file selected'})

    if file:
        filename = secure_filename(file.filename)
        local_path = os.path.join(api.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], filename)
        file.save(local_path)
        mime = mimetypes.guess_type(local_path)[0]
        # Get the user's UID
        user_uid = request.user['uid']

        # Process the file as needed
        try:
            EmbedPDF(local_path, user_uid)
        except:
            api.logger.critical('Cant create Chroma with the User ID: %s', user_uid, exc_info=0)
            return jsonify({"response": "Cant get or create User in Chroma Server"})

        # Upload the processed file to Firebase Storage
        destination_path = f'uploads/{filename}'
        file_url = upload_blob(local_path, destination_path)
        os.remove(local_path)

        # Create a new document in the Firestore database
        file_ref = db.collection('uploaded_files').document()

        # Add file metadata to the document
        file_data = {
            'user_uid': user_uid,
            'filename': filename,
            'mimetype': mime,
            'file_url': file_url,
            'upload_timestamp': datetime.datetime.utcnow()
        }
        file_ref.set(file_data)

        return jsonify({'response': 'File uploaded, processed, and indexed successfully', 'file_url': file_url})


@api.route('/chat', methods=['POST'])
@check_token
def chat():
    data = request.get_json()
    if not data or "message" not in data:
        return ("message parameter is required", 400)

    user_uid = request.user['uid']
    vectorstore = Chroma(embedding_function=embeddings,
                         persist_directory=user_uid)

    if vectorstore:
        message = data["message"]
        results = vectorstore.similarity_search(message)

        if not results:
            return jsonify({"response": "I couldn't find a relevant response in the documents."})

        results[0] = results[0].dict()
        results[1] = results[1].dict()
        results[2] = results[2].dict()
        results[3] = results[3].dict()

        qa = ConversationalRetrievalChain.from_llm(OpenAI(
            temperature=0, openai_api_key=OPEN_AI_API_KEY), vectorstore.as_retriever(), return_source_documents=True)

        result = qa(
            {"question": message, "chat_history": get_chathistory(user_uid)})

        # Save chat message and response to Firestore
        result['source_documents'][0] = result['source_documents'][0].dict()
        result['source_documents'][1] = result['source_documents'][1].dict()
        result['source_documents'][2] = result['source_documents'][2].dict()
        result['source_documents'][3] = result['source_documents'][3].dict()

        save_chat_message(user_uid, message, result['answer'], result['source_documents'][0],
                          result['source_documents'][1], result['source_documents'][2], result['source_documents'][3])

        return result

    else:
        return jsonify({"response": "No documents indexed for this user."})


@api.route('/download/<file_id>', methods=['GET'])
@check_token
def download_file(file_id):
    user_uid = request.user['uid']

    if check_file_owner(user_uid, file_id):
        file_ref = db.collection('uploaded_files').document(file_id)
        file_data = file_ref.get().to_dict()
        # file_url = file_data['file_url']

        filename = file_data['filename']

        # get a reference to the file in storage
        file_ref = bucket.blob('uploads/' + filename)

        # download the file to a temporary location
        temp_file = f"/tmp/{filename}"
        r = file_ref.download_as_string()

        with tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile() as f:
            f.write(r)
            f.seek(0)
            return send_file(f.name, as_attachment=True, download_name=filename)
    else:
        return jsonify({"response": "You do not have permission to access this file."})

@api.route('/delete_file/<file_id>', methods=["GET"])
@check_token
def delete_file(file_id):
    user_uid = request.user['uid']
    if check_file_owner(user_uid, file_id):
        # delete the file from Firebase Storage
        file_ref = db.collection('uploaded_files').document(file_id)
        file_data = file_ref.get().to_dict()
        filename = file_data['filename']
        file_ref.delete()
        bucket.blob('uploads/' + filename).delete()
        return jsonify({"response": "File deleted successfully."})
    else:
        return jsonify({"response": "You do not have permission to delete this file."})
```

Already tried it on another system and reinstalling. Found some Topics about other packages that it may have something to do with the modules used python versions

Comment: That code is using older syntax that only works with Python 2.x.